# Usar GET para listar los elementos en un array publicados previamente por POST

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Paso a explicar más detalladamente el tema porque realmente no sé si logré explicar bien mi situación en el título.

Estoy cursando Full-stack dev y actualmente estamos aprendiendo a guardar información de formularios (en memoria, aún sin base de datos) con un POST (todo esto usando Nodejs con Express, y jsonwebtoken. PD: Se me dificulta bastante el lado Backend del desarrollo, desde antes de cursar tengo pensado ir por el camino del Front-end, pero este curso es el único que estaba disponible ahora).

Hasta ahí pude lograrlo de a poco, pero ahora la consigna es, listar en un array los elementos creados que salieron del formulario con POST.

Acá dejo la ruta asociada al formulario POST (aún no está conectada con el frontend):

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const formData = [];

router.post('/form', (req, res) => {

  if (req.body.projectName && req.body.projectDescription && req.body.projectLanguageSelected && req.body.projectRoleNeeded) {
  
    const newProject = {
      projectName: req.body.projectName,
      projectDescription: req.body.projectDescription, 
      projectLanguageSelected: req.body.projectLanguageSelected, 
      projectRoleNeeded: req.body.projectRoleNeeded
    }

    formData.push(newProject);
    return res.json({ success: true, newProject });
  }
  else {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Faltan datos (requeridos: project_name, project_description, project_languageSelected, project_roleNeeded)'});
  }
      }
)

module.exports = router;
```

Estoy realmente perdido ahora que tengo que listar lo que se registre de allí en una ruta diferente con GET, así que cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Desde ya muchísimas gracias al/los que se tomó/tomaron el tiempo de leer mi pregunta :).

Comment: Debes crear otro endpoint (es decir, otra ruta) `/listar` en donde sea de tipo get y esta pueda ser mostrar el JSON que generaste en el tu método post. Si ya tienes los datos guardos, en otra ruta de tipo get ahi es donde mostrarias los datos previamente almecenados.

Comment: Asumo que lo que quieres es pedir que el servidor te envíe el array `formData` cuando hagas una petición GET, ¿me equivoco?

Comment: `formData` siempre va a estar vacía cada vez que se ejecute ese código. Si querés que mantenga el valor entre un llamado y otro tendrías que almacenarla en algún lado o declararla en el front-end y después incluirla en la URL del GET.

Comment: N.N, observa bien el código. `formData` está declarado fuera del controlador, por lo tanto mientras el servidor se mantenga en marcha, el array va a seguir conservando el contenido.

Comment: @EdgarGc Muchas gracias!!, voy a estar viendo eso cuando esté en la pc :) Actualizo en cuanto lo tenga solucionado.

Comment: @MarcosRodríguez Exactamente. Que todos los datos que salgan en el POST del form me aparezcan en la ruta del GET cuando haga dicha petición :)

Comment: @N.N. Ya lo dijo Marcos, pero por ahora por temas de que en el curso aún no hemos dado otra forma de almacenar los datos en otro lado que no sea en memoria mientras el servidor corra.

Comment: @Marcos Rodríguez ¿pero cuando se ejecute el controlador que maneje el GET de dónde va a obtener esa información? ¿Se guarda automáticamente en sesión o algo así?

Comment: @N.N. Fíjate que si haces una llamada al endpoint POST, el cuerpo se añade a un objeto (newProject) y después al formData se le hace push con dicho objeto. Puedes guardar la información que quieras en una variable, que si viene otro usuario desde un navegador diferente y te pide el contenido de esta, va a ver exactamente lo mismo. Las sesiones se gestionan de otra forma usando stores y la cookie `connect.sid` de express-session

Comment: @Marcos Rodríguez Ah que interesante, no sabía que funcionaba así. Borro los comentarios para evitar spam si les parece bien.

Comment: @N.N. No los borres!! Pueden ser útiles para otros usuarios que no comprenden bien el funcionamiento de Node!! Tu confusión puede ayudar a otros ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confío al 99% de que tú solito eres capaz de solucionar ese problema que tienes... Pero te dejo aquí una ayuda y de paso un bonus de la respuesta que escribí y oculté al rato porque no era lo que se preguntaba, tal vez te venga bien algún día.

### Enviar contenido de una variable del servidor por GET.

Esto es tan simple como declarar una ruta para una petición GET:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const formData = [];

// Escucha peticiones GET desde la ruta listFormData
router.get('/listFormData', (req, res) => {
    // Envía el contenido del array formData.
    res.json(formData);
});

router.post('/form', (req, res) => {
    // Controlador de form.
});
```

Y no te preocupes por el backend, al principio se hace bastante cuesta arriba, cuando aprendes a dominar lo básico, se te hace muchísimo más fácil manejarlo, créeme, yo también quería ser de frontend y al final me he quedado en fullstack (porque no me queda otra, pero me gusta más el backend).

### Bonus de respuesta incorrecta

> Para recoger los datos usando el método GET, tendrás que capturar la consulta integrada en la url.

Esto lo puedes hacer desde los parámetros de la petición (`request`)

Te muestro un controlador básico:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // Coge el parámetro 'nombre' de la ruta (el name del input en el form).
    const { nombre } = req.query;
    // Responde un json con un mensaje.
    res.json({msg: `Hola, ${nombre}`});
})
```

Y prueba a hacer una consulta con este HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost:3000/">
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Espero que te sirva y mucho ánimo aprendiendo, cuesta pero compensa muchísimo, créeme.

Comment: Tremendo! Voy a partir de esta base, muchas gracias por el Bonus al final y agradezco mucho la confianza en poder resolver el problema por mi cuenta :). Veremos al final en dónde termine, si más backend, frontend o fullstack, pero como bien dijiste al principio está bastante cuesta arriba. Un saludo!

Comment: @Rektiem Si yo he podido "dominar" Node, tú también, esto es más fácil de lo que parece, el problema es que impone un poco y hay muchos conceptos que asimilar. Por cierto, mírate la desestructuración de objetos, para sacar datos del body te ahorrará mucho tiempo cuando envíes bastante información, y no tendrás que repetirte tanto accediendo a `req.body`. Suerte aprendiendo!!